# Builder pattern and Unlimited arguments

Tags: java, oop, instantiation, builder

Utilizing the builder pattern I noticed that in some cases it would be ideal to change several values at once with builder methods passing unlimited arguments.

For example, say I wanted to do something like so:

```
public class Element {
    String name;
    Double fire, water, earth, air, dark, light;

    Element(Builder e) {
        name = e.name;
        fire = e.fire; water = e.water; earth = e.earth;
        air = e.air; dark = e.dark; light = e.light;
    }

    static class Builder {
        String name;
        // Default multipliers
        Double fire = 1.0, water = 1.0, earth = 1.0, air = 1.0, dark = 1.0, light = 1.0; 

        Builder(String name){ this.name = name; }

        public Builder setRes(Double... element) {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) { element[i] = 0.5; }
            return this;
        }
        public Builder setVuln(Double... element) {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) { element[i] = 2.0; }
            return this;
        }
        public Builder setImmune(Double... element) {
            for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) { element[i] = 0.0; }
            return this;
        }

        public Element create(){ return new Element(this); }
    }   
}
```

This compiles without error. The types may only hold definite values either 0, 0.5, 1 or 2. Given multiple 'elements' it is what came to mind circumvent having to create 3 methods per 'element' but the problem and thus my question is on once the time comes to instantiate a new element -- how would/could this work? Is it even possible or am I stuck making multiple methods?

The reason I ask is that I don't see how it would be possible to pass the values of an instance that hasn't yet been initialized.

Intuition would have me(incorrectly) do this

```
Element nora = new Element.Builder("Nora").setVuln(nora.dark, nora.light).create();
```

Comment: the assignments like this `element[i] = 0.5;` will not work as you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would perhaps change the model to hold a map of element type to multiplier using an `Enum` and when building elements, passing the `Enum` fields for "resistance", "vulnerability" and "immunity" similar to the following:

```
public enum ElementType {

    DARK,
    LIGHT // ...
}

public class Element {
    String name;
    Map<ElementType, Double> multipliers = ...;

    // ...

    public Builder vulnerability(ElementType... elementTypes) {
        for (ElementType elementType : elementTypes) {
            multipliers.put(elementType , 2.0);
        }
        return this;
    }
}


Element nora = new Element.Builder("Nora").vulnerability(ElementType.DARK, ElementType.LIGHT).create();
```